# jquery ui resizable returning the size

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-resizable

Hay im new to jquery and i'm trying to use resizable. I can get it to work fine but cant seem to work out how to return the new size. I would like to set the new size's to a php variables to be save in a DB. I am new to javascript and jquery so any help would be a big help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The resizable plugin itself does not provide a method to get the sizes.  I assume they did not implement this because it would just be redundancy methods on the same node, as there are already methods in jQuery core for doing this.

jQuery provides several ways to find width and height depending on what you want to do.  The plain width/height methods get the css values. A lot of times it can be more useful to use the outerWidth and outerHeight methods, however, because they return the total calculated size of the element on the page, including all margins, borders, etc.

Examples:

```
//Width/Height of just the element (as from css)
var w = $('.selector').width()
var h = $('.selector').height()

//Width/Height of total space the element takes up with formatting (includes border and margin)
var w = $('.selector').outerWidth()
var h = $('.selector').outerHeight()

//Width/Height of the space the content of the element takes up
var w = $('.selector').innerWidth()
var h = $('.selector').innerHeight()
```

**Edit** Applying the methods to resizable events

The resizable plugin offers several events to bind to: create,start,resize, and stop.  We can bind a function to get called on any of these events at initialization or any time later.  As it sounds, the start event fires when you start to resize the element, stop fires when you stop resizing the element, and resize gets called everytime the size of the element changes during resizing (every pixel).

Binding at initialization:

```
$('.selector').resizable({
    //Other options
    create : function(event,ui) {...},
    start : function(event,ui) {...},
    stop : function(event,ui) {...},
    resize : function(event,ui) {...}
});
```

Or binding at any point later

```
$('.selector').bind('resizecreate',function(event,ui) {...});
$('.selector').bind('resizestart',function(event,ui) {...});
$('.selector').bind('resizestop',function(event,ui) {...});
$('.selector').bind('resize',function(event,ui) {...});
```

Now, for your case, I would suggest 1 of 2 options, either binding the start and stop commands to get your original and modified sizes, or binding to resize to work with the value in real time.

Example for start/stop pattern

```
var startW = 0;
var startH = 0;

$('.selector').resizable({
    //Other options
    start : function(event,ui) {
        startW = $(this).outerWidth();
        startH = $(this).outerHeight();
    },
    stop : function(event,ui) {
        endW = $(this).outerWidth();
        endH = $(this).outerHeight();
        alert("width changed:"+ (endW-startW) + " -- Height changed:" + (endH-endW));
    }
});
```

Example for printing value on the move to console

```
$('.selector').resizable({
    //other options
    resize: function(event,ui) {
        console.log([$(this).outerWidth(),$(this).outerHeight()]);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That work for giving me the start width and height but what is i want the new one is there a good way i can echo it on the fly maybe

Comment: Just call it on the fly...specifically with the resizable plugin, you can use the events to get it when you need...see the edit for examples

Answer (score 4):

Things may have been different at the time of these answers, but now jQuery UI makes it very easy to get information on your events and ui elements. I highly recommend console logging the ui variable, as ther eis a LOT of information available from it. However to answer your question a little bit better:

```
$('.selector').resizable({
    stop: function (evt, ui) {
        console.log(ui.size);
    }
});
```

should yield an object with properties height and width. These are your new heights and widths of your resizable items

In case you wanted to calculate the delta of either of these values, you could reference `ui.originalSize` and either the height or width properties there as well.

Hope this works out a little more concisely than the other answers

Answer (score 2):

example div:

```
<div id="div">
    <p>this is the div i want to retrieve demensions</p>

    <p>second paragraph</p>
</div>
```

retrieve the dimensions with this javascript

```
var width = $("#div").css("width"),
    height =$("#div").css("height");

alert (width + ", " + height);
```

to write the dimensions back to the database will you will need to POST the values back as either part of a `form` or via an AJAX request