# JQuery ui resizable returning the size (animate:true)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resizable

There is a similar Post: [JQuery ui resizable returning the size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8468680/jquery-ui-resizable-returning-the-size?) and the Solution without animation works fine.
**BUT** if u have sth like:

```js
$( myElement ).resizable({
        ghost: true,        
        grid: [ 320, 300 ],
        handles: 'se',
        maxHeight: 580,
        maxWidth: 940,
        stop : function(event,ui) {
            elementWidth = $(this).width();
            elementHeight = $(this).height();
            console.log(elementWidth);
            console.log(elementHeight);
        },
        animate: true // bullshit causing
    });
```

with `animate: true` it gives me always the width/height before it was rezised.

Any Ideas?

Thank You - L.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, maybe not the best splution, but works!
Adding an `Timeout` with `duration` as long as ur `animteDuration`

```js
stop : function(event,ui) {
            setTimeout(function()
            {
                elementWidth = $(urElement).width();
                elementHeight = $(urElement).height();   
             }, 300); //timeout as long as ur animation duration

        },
```